# Are black holes diplanar? Is there an inside and an outside? or two sides with separate qualities?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

I’ve seen other posts throughout stackexchange that say a black hole may exhibit having a universe within/across it’s event horizon. does this make a black hole diplanar? or if not, is there a better way to label/describe this quality?

Comment: What do you think quantum entanglement is?

Comment: I thought it was when two particles moved exactly alike

Comment: entanglement is just when some property of one particle can be determined by doing a measurement on another particle. It doesn't in any way that they simply do the same thing at all times. Most entangled particles, experimentally, are for example, moving in opposite directions.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's just light reflecting off you, then reflecting off the mirror, then going into your eye. There is no object in the mirror, and there is no quantum entanglement happening.

Comment: That would make more sense than what I thought it was. Thanks for the clarification